# Do any other particles get excited(or absorb energy) by photons like electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, visible-light, electrons

Electrons get excited to different energy levels when photons of specific frequencies fall on them.But, is there other particles which absorb the energy of the photons?

Comment: Yes, photons are the mediators of the electric force, and so they interact with any particle with non-zero charge.

Comment: @DavidH Sir, are the particles that pop in and out of existence which constitute vacuum charged?

Comment: Sure. Electrons and positrons for example.

Comment: @DavidH, particles with magnetic dipole moment, too, no?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example nuclei can be resonantly excited in magnetic fields with photons from the radio frequency band, like in NMR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, photons are the interactors of electromagnetic force, so they interact with every particle that has non 0 charge or non 0 magnetic angolar momentum. That means both spin (intrinsic angolar momentum) or orbital angular momentum.